# Firebase: How can I use the same custom token for authentication from different environments (JS and iOS)?

Tags: php, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the same token(server-side generated - PHP) to auth the user in web(JS) and iOS app(SDK). These are the steps I do to auth a user:

1. generate a JWT token:

I am using using the recommended lib https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php:

```
$generator = new TokenGenerator($firebaseSecret);
$token = $generator->setOption('expires', strtotime('+1 day'))
    ->setData(array('uid' => $user->id))
    ->create();
```

2. use the token to auth the user via Javascript:

   ```
   ref.authWithCustomToken(token, registerHandler);
   registerHandler: function(error, authData)
   {
       if (error) {
           console.log("Login Failed!", error);
       } else {
           console.log("Login Success!");
   }
   ```

All works correctly, the FIRST time, the user is logged in and ready to roll.(Firebase session set to 1 year)

However:

1. if I logout and use the same method to login again, with the same token, I get the following error: "INVALID_TOKEN: Failed to validate MAC.". If I use another fresh token all works again.
2. If I send the token(unused) to the iOS app I am also working with, I get the above error all the time.

Can somebody share some light into this situation ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem myself, in the end. I'll post this here so that future devs avoid the issue I ran into.

Be always careful about where you store your data. My tokens were stored into the DB, in a varchar type column, but they were bigger then 256 chars, so they were not saved properly. After changing the column type everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: What type did you use?